# Does Redis Caching return a Case sensitive data while integrating with java?

Tags: spring, caching, redis

We have a requirement where we get the data from an external system and store it in Redis Cache and retrieve it using Spring Cacheable annotation. The issue is the client is expecting the data to be case sensitive. Is it possible to achieve this using redis or by doing any configurations in redis.

Comment: Either use Spring-Cache or Use Spring-Redis, choose one.  Also, Key in Redis is case-sensitive, value you can always insert an object or so.

Comment: We are clear about using spring redis. The issue here is we using this to store the data for a Country field. so our Key is (countries) and we have 250 countries stored against the same key. When the user types ahead something like (In) i need to retrieve the India and Indonesia. My question is can we get India and Indonesia irrespective of whatever case the type ahead is in. The existing data is retrieved only when the case matches against the case in which the data is stored in redis

Comment: For this, you will have to ask Redis with key In. My point is, anyways, you will be sending this data to backend, then why not Upper-case or Lower-case all search queries you are getting. And save the keys also that way. This way India will be saved as INDIA. When the user types In(Front-end)-->Your_Controller_Mapping-->toUpperCase and send it to retrieve the Value. Can you tell me why this would not be applicable in your case?

Comment: Also, if just Countries is your problem, then Java has a countries package which you can use. That would be more simple.

Comment: Our current implementation is exactly the same as you have mentioned. we have set our values for the key countries in upper case and UI have ensured that what ever the user types we receive that in upper case. We have another requirement for a field societies which is again a type ahead but the client does not want us to return the data in upper case. Instead he wants us to return the data for the society key in Pascal case irrespective of the case the user types in.

Comment: Which is why we trying to check for case sensitive configuration or an approach. [The data for societies key received from the external system is in Pascal case and also it is stored in the same case in redis]

Comment: Ok, Let's start with the beginning, Redis is not the stuff which is generally used to do such tasks. It is used when time is very important or the number of requests are like more than 1000 per second or so. So, my question is why are you using Redis and not simple DB queries?

Comment: We are using redis because we are implementing auto complete functionality for certain fields and the data for these fields come from external system. Secondly this would be an incremental data as there would be weekly new data updates. Thirdly, the client dosent wants to have a dependency on db or external system, hence maintaining a redis server. Also some of the fields are Autocomplete cum Drop Downs. Hence for the drop downs redis caching is integrated with Spring.

Comment: Ur requirements are complex to say the least. Secondly, what ur hoping for cannot be achieved until the key is precise. This is a security measure, I hope someone with more knowledge can help u out, but this looks problematic. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Redis keys and values are case sensitive by design. Redis isn't a complex database, it is an in memory key-value store.

Hence the answer is no, that's not possible.

The obvious workaround is storing everything lower case, and transforming your data to lower case as well before requiring a key.